# Appendices title in ToC without appendices list

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, appendices

How can I make that the appendices list (numbered with `\chapter{}`) not appear in ToC, but appears the title "Appendices" instead. I'm using the `book` documentclass, and the default `\appendix` command to begin the appendices.

In ToC, I have this:

```
1. CHAPTER ...
   1.1 Section ...

A. Appendix A ...
   A.1 Section ...

B. Appendix B ...
   B.1 Section ...
```

I need this:

```
1. CHAPTER ...
   1.1 Section ...

Appendices ...
```

But, I also need the Appendix A and B numbered in document.

Some solutions raise change the `tocdepth` counter after the declaration of the start of the appendices, but can interfere with other lists (LoT, LoF) and the package hyperref and PDF bookmarks.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{hidelinks}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoftables
  \blinddocument
  \begin{table}\centering
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Test}
  \end{table}
  \appendix
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The solution should not affect the other lists and PDF bookmarks.

Comment: `\chapter*{Appendices}`?

Comment: @You No, I need that numbering at the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach by the »[appendix](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix)« package and the decreased counter `tocdepth` written to the ToC results in a ToC entry for the appendices without disabling the numbering of the single appendix chapters in the document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \blinddocument  % drop in actual document

  \begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
    \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
    \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

---

According to the mentioned demands I can only offer a quick hack of the involved macros that write content to the ToC and the LoT.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoftables
  \blinddocument

  \begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Dummy table}
    \label{tab:dummy}
    \centering
    \rule{4in}{2.25in}
  \end{table}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
%                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
%                                    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
%                     \else
%                       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
%                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
%                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
%     \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
%       \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
%         \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
%       \fi
%       #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
%       \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
%         \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
%           \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
%         \fi
%         #7}
    }%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

  \begin{appendices}
    \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
    \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The critical parts are commented to prevent corresponding entries.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice, but this solution seems to be interfering with other lists (LoT, Lof), and also with bookmarks of the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @osjerick: Perhaps the second example is useful.

Comment: since the lof and lot are triggered separately, why not just restore the original `tocdepth` before the `\tableof...` instructions?

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's not too easy. :)

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Great solution! Thanks! I prefer this kind of solutions instead the use of many packages.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate a bit? I tried with restoring `tocdepth` but somehow couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

this is a riff on @Thorsten's example, which really provides the mechanism
for modifying the `tocdepth`.  this is presented as an answer only because
i didn't want to pollute his example with code that he might not understand.
(in a comment, he requested an elaboration, and this is too extensive for a comment.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{+1}
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables

  \blinddocument  % drop in actual document

  \begin{figure}
    this is a figure.
    \caption{dummy figure}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{table}
    \caption{dummy table}
    this is a table.
  \end{table}

  \begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
    \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
    \begin{figure}
      this is a figure.
      \caption{dummy figure}
    \end{figure}
    \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
    \begin{table}
      \caption{dummy table}
      this is a table.
    \end{table}
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

in order to suppress the listing of separate appendices in the toc, Thorsten
reduced the `tocdepth` by one.  to restore the full listing of figures and tables,
here the reverse of that technique is used to negate the change before calling
`\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.

no modification of definitions necessary.  all potential information is
automatically written to the `.toc`, `.lof` and `.lot` files, and `\tocdepth`
just specifies which entries to ignore, so it's not necessary to modify what
is *written* to these files.

Comment: Ah, yes. Many thanks for that. I knew that there must be something trivial.